# Scala Creating combination by Key efficiently

Tags: scala, mapreduce, mapping, expand

## Update

Original file is a text file that is in a form of

`( record_id, element )
 ( 1         1 2 3    )
 ( 2         2 5 6 7  )`

I used the following function to read input file:
`sc.textFile(input)`

and process it into the records array format below.

=========================================================================
Here is a sample an array in scala im working in

Records Array looks like below:

```
Array(Record_Id ,  Array(Element) )
     ( 1        ,  Array(1,2,3  ) )
     ( 2        ,  Array(2,5,6,7) )
     ....
```

I wrote a scala map function to extract prefix(dynamically in here i take first half of the elements) of each array

```
val prefix = records.map(x => ((x._1, x._2) ,(x._2.take((x._2.size*0.5).ceil ))) )
```

Which will give me

```
Array(Record_Id ,  Array(Element) , Prefix)
     ( 1        ,  Array(1,2,3  ) , Array(1,2))
     ( 2        ,  Array(2,5,6,7) , Array(2,5))
     ....
```

Now I try to generate a RDD that uses each prefix as key, Which would look like something like this:

```
  (Prefix , Array(Record_Id ,  Array(Element) )
  ( 1    ,  (1             ,  Array(1,2,3  ) )
  ( 2    ,  (1             ,  Array(1,2,3  ) )
  ( 2    ,  (2             ,  Array(2,5,6,7) )
  ( 5    ,  (2             ,  Array(2,5,6,7) )
  ....
```

I tried the following:

```
val pairedWithKey = prefix.map{case (k,v) => v.map(i => k ->i)}
```

It works perfectly on small volume data.
However, once i use this in a larger datasets it will take forever to load.
I'm still new to scala, it would be great if anyone can direct me on how to improve the performance of this operation.

Comment: is your array already a rdd or just normal array in scala? how do you read your data into array? can you update that

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Updated in my original post, it is in rdd already. I used sc.textFile to read in the text file and the processing time is quick regardless of how of many records the original text file has. It only starts taking a long time after the following line `val pairedWithKey = prefix.map{case (k,v) => v.map(i => k ->i)}`

Comment: Why do you have `Array` instead of `Rdd` everywhere ? What do you have in your file ? What is the type of your initial Rdd ?

Comment: I just used Array to visualise the data structure.
it was a text file originally